# gridview row onclick event prevent template button onclick in each row to fire in google chrome and safari but it works in IE and firefox

Tags: c#, gridview, onclick, c#-2.0, buttonclick

I have a gridview,inside each row I have a button with commandName "Activate".
I also add onclick behaviour to gridview row to select the row and show the form with some info. the problem is: when i click on button instead of Activate command, Select command will fire.

here is how I did this:

```
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button CommandName="Activate" ID="btnActivate" runat="server" Text="Activate" CausesValidation="false"></asp:Button>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle Wrap="false" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

then I manage the command here:

```
 protected void gridview_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
            switch (e.CommandName.ToUpper())
            {
                case "SELECT":
                    GridViewRow row1=(GridViewRow)grvCustomerCredit.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)];
                    selectedRowIndex = row1.RowIndex;
                    txbCC_CITY.Text = row1.Cells[4].Text;
                    txbCC_PROVINCE.Text = row1.Cells[5].Text;
                    row1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                    break;
                case "ACTIVATE":
                    GridViewRow row2 = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).Parent.Parent;
                    creditID = Convert.ToInt32(gridview.DataKeys[row2.RowIndex].Value);
                    {do the Activate Action}
                    break;
            }
     }
```

and this is how I add onclick on each row:

```
  protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gridview.Rows)
        {
            row.Attributes.Add("onclick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(gv, "Select$" + row.RowIndex.ToString(), true));
        }
        base.Render(writer);
    }
```

before adding the onclick on gridview row Activate button was working fine. how can I set the first priority to button click not row click? any idea?

Comment: I have doubt regarding your Question , As per code default Activate only called . So for why u mentioned render function. I m not aware of that,if you Know means please explain me..

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gridview.Rows)
    {
        row.Attributes.Add("onclick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(gv, "Select$" + row.RowIndex.ToString(), true));
    }
    base.Render(writer);
}
```

In this Function you are mention "select" , so for only its take the select Function.
Replace into

```
 row.Attributes.Add("onclick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(gv, "ACTIVATE$" + row.RowIndex.ToString(), true));
```